# Symfony2 redirect /admin/* to /admin/login when not logged in (or use FOSUserBundle?)

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I am new to Symfony and I am trying to build an admin interface.  I have an existing users table and all I want is to secure the `^/admin.+` path with a login page at `/admin/login` and Symfony seems to be very tutorial-oriented with little explanation on how to customize anything. (or at least, not much info on how each piece component works together with the others)

Here is my security.yml

```
encoders:
    AppBundle\Entity\Users:
        algorithm:        sha1
        encode_as_base64: false
        iterations:       1

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH ]

providers:
    administrators:
        entity: { class: AppBundle:Users, property: email }
    in_memory:
        memory: ~

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        anonymous: ~

    admin_area:
        pattern:    ^/admin
        anonymous:  ~
        provider:   administrators
        form_login:
            default_target_path: /admin
            check_path: /admin/login_check
            login_path: /admin/login
            remember_me: true
        logout:
            path:   /admin/logout
            target: /admin

access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

When I go to /admin I get error page with "Full authentication is required to access this resource."  What I want is for the app to redirect from `/admin/*` (except /admin/login of course) to `/admin/login` when not logged in.

**Notes & Other Questions**

Symfony seems to want you to *always* use certain existing bundles and I have scoured the web for info on how to understand what's actually happening but only seem to find more and more tutorials.

Should I even be using FOSUserBundle?  If so, can I use my existing users table or do I have to use their schema?

Comment: Change your check_path to just /admin/login (it is okay to use the same path as login_path).  As it stands right not, accessing /admin/login_check required admin privileges.  FOSUserBundle will not buy you anything in this context.  In fact, even though it is the most popular bundle out there it is sadly under maintained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the order of firewalls, so make admin_area before main

```
admin_area:
    pattern:    ^/admin
    anonymous:  ~
    provider:   administrators
    form_login:
        default_target_path: /admin
        check_path: /admin/login_check
        login_path: /admin/login
        remember_me: true
    logout:
        path:   /admin/logout
        target: /admin

main:
    anonymous: ~
```

**Explication**

In our example, the main firewall doesn't contain pattern, then if it's defined in first order it will take all routes. so in this firewall (main) we don't define the form_login then we get the error page with "Full authentication is required to access this resource.".

In another way, if you add the pattern in the main firewall, you will not have the error (see the example above)

```
main:
    pattern: /home
    anonymous: ~
admin_area:
    pattern:    ^/admin
    anonymous:  ~
    provider:   administrators
    form_login:
        default_target_path: /admin
        check_path: /admin/login_check
        login_path: /admin/login
        remember_me: true
    logout:
        path:   /admin/logout
        target: /admin
```

Comment: Concerning fosuserbundle is a library built on top of Symfony’s security system, which provides functionality such as registration, login, password resets, etc. It has built in support for MongoDB, as well as ORMs such as Doctrine, Propel, etc.
FOSUserBundle requires us to create a User entity that needs to be persisted into the database. The bundle already provides an abstract base class with most of the fields that we need. We just need to create the entity that extends this base class.

Comment: Now I get a redirect loop after moving admin_area above main.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Nvm that fixed it.  Mind editing your answer with an explanation as to _why_ `admin_area` should come before `main`?  Thanks